# Why does cw followed by ctrl-r register consist of two edits?

Tags: normal-mode, register, repeated-commands, undo-redo

I did <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> at the beginning of a word to paste the content of register `a` in its place. And this, I thought, is done entering insert mode only once; or at least, never going back to normal mode.

It obviously worked, and I pressed <kbd>Escape</kbd> to go back to normal mode.

Then I realized I had picked the wrong register, so I hit <kbd>u</kbd> to undo the change.

But this only reverted part of the change, as I had done <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>Escape</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>.

I've also verified that `.` also only replayed the <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>. Well, not quite because it enters insert mode before doing that.

What is this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this in `vim --clean` (`:let @a = 'my'<cr>Ithis is your word<esc>Fycw<C-r>a<esc>u`). Perhaps [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)? I've seem some emulators work this way though, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out, it's [vim-peekaboo](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-peekaboo) which is causing this behavior, and it is a known bug, filed in [#30](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-peekaboo/issues/30).